# Spring does not login with angular frontend request header field cache-control is not allowed

Tags: angular, spring

I created the following application in angular with backend java in spring. When I go to login, I get the following error and I can not understand why

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/oauth/token?username=admin&password=secret&grant_type=password`
>   from origin `http://localhost:4200` has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Request header field cache-control is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Would anyone know how to help me solve it?
Surely it will be a nonsense, but I'm losing a lot of time with no results

Thank you all

https://github.com/rox-ale/angular-login

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you only have CORS enabled in the controller using the @CrossOrigin annotation. I think further configuration is required in in your LoginConfig class

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login","/oauth/authorize",
            "/oauth/confirm_access")
            .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

For reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use proxy for your calls to the API, it's the easy way to workaround CORS exceptions. You can use this method even if you don't have access to the server. [Here](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/) is the guide how to configure proxy in Angular

Answer (score 0):

in your `login` method where you build the headers with

```
  let headers = new Headers(
    {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'Authorization': auth
    });
```

remove setting the *Cache-Control* header:

```
  let headers = new Headers(
    {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': auth
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the filter of oAuth is before the cors filter on filterChain. A workaround is to add your customized Cors Filter and set the order to the HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE.

Something like that:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Cache-Control");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "180");
    if(!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        return;
    }
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());

}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```